# Error when integrate Sinch library in Swift?

Tags: swift, push-notification, sinch

I have my own app to integrate Sinch in order to call video. My big bug is when user A calling to user B, user C and all other users also received the notification for incoming call (both applications of user B and C are background). 
Here is my code for getting local notification. In the `headers` of `call`, i pass 3 parameters: remote user id, caller name and caller avatar. I try to print out but it shows `nil`. I think the solution is put current user id equal to remote user id but i can not get anything from the `headers`, please show me how to fix this.

```
func client(_ client: SINCallClient!, localNotificationForIncomingCall call: SINCall!) -> SINLocalNotification! {

        print("notificationcall \(call?.headers)")

        let notification = SINLocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = "Cuộc gọi call video"
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        return notification
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload you need to get the remoteId from header and in handleRemoteNotification check if the localUser is the same of remoteId if is it ! you need you show the notification of video call and if not ignore this notification!

Comment: Thanks for your helping, i solve my bug. One more problem, when kill app, i don’t receive any notification. How can i fix this ?

Comment: check in your iphone the  settings > General > BackgroundAppRefresh>and enable backgroundAppRefresh for your app

Comment: check if the  self.push = Sinch.managedPush(with: SINAPSEnvironment.development) not production